# Error django: AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'Home'

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to implement the ability to login and logout into my django site and I'm getting the following error when attempting to use the command python manage.py runserver while in the virtual environment. I'm using django 2.2

my porject:

```
realtime
 |-core
 |-nodejs
 |-realtime
  |-templates
  | |-index.html
  |-url.py
```

my code url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Home/$', views.Home, name='Home'),
    url(r'^node_api$', views.node_api, name='node_api'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html')),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name=template_name), name='logout'),
]
```

core\views.py

```
from core.models import Comments, User

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

import redis

@login_required
def home(request):
    comments = Comments.objects.select_related().all()[0:100]
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())

@csrf_exempt
def node_api(request):
    try:
        #Get User from sessionid
        session = Session.objects.get(session_key=request.POST.get('sessionid'))
        user_id = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        #Create comment
        Comments.objects.create(user=user, text=request.POST.get('comment'))

        #Once comment has been created post it to the chat channel
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        r.publish('chat', user.username + ': ' + request.POST.get('comment'))

        return HttpResponse("Everything worked :)")
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(str(e))
```

Comment: Add your views file. The error is coming from your views, so that may be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible you imported *mutliple* items as `views`?

Comment: What is the expected outcome here? What makes you think `django.contrib.auth.views` would have a `Home` view? If you have written a `Home` view, you should import that using that module path. `from myown.views import home` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

On the line

```
url(r'Home/$', views.Home, name='Home'),
```

the view `Home` is loaded from module `views` which refer to this import:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
```

Since `django.contrib.auth.views` does NOT define any class or function `Home`, you get your error.

You probably forgot to import your app's `views` module:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
import core.views as my_app_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Home/$', my_app_views.home, name='Home'),
    url(r'^node_api$', my_app_views.node_api, name='node_api'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name=template_name), name='logout'),
]
```

Please note that in this new version, `django.contrib.auth.views` is imported with name `auth_views` and your custom app's `views` is imported with name `my_app_views`. This will prevent any confusion when calling views from one app or another

Comment: there is an error: `import .views as my_app_views
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I fixed, but  `from . import views as my_app_views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'`

Comment: Of course... You have to adapt the import to your own code. I don't know where is your view stored, and you didn't provide enough information in your question. You have to import your views module or your views functions or class and use them in your urlpatterns list

Comment: Answer edited, but you really have to understand the Python import system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182725/discussion-between-antwane-and-tran-quoc-gia-cat).